# return JSON in Spring MVC 4

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring mvc and I wish to create a RESTful service.
I create a controller,maps a function to URL and when I try to access it instead of a JSON I receive a 406 error.

I guess there is some trouble with the configuration(Java configuration) but I can't find what it is.

here is my WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.yated.web.controller")
public class WebConfig {

}
```

here is my WebInitializer:

public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}
}
```

and here is the controller:

```
@RestController
public class EventsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/events")
    public List<String> getEvents()
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Event1");
        list.add("Event2");

        return list;
    }
}
```

and as I said when I try to access:
http://localhost:8181/web/events
or
http://localhost:8181/web/events.json

I get http error 406

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have FasterXML's Jackson library on your classpath?

Comment: No but I added jackson-mapper-asl to my POM.xml and that did the job.
Thanks!